# How can I push all private methods to the end of a file in Visual Studio automatically?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper

I have a long class with tests and I have the tests intermixed with helper methods that are private I want all y test to be at the top foe easy read and access, is there an automatic way to do this, maybe an extension or a Resharper method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resharper [Code Clean-up](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/01/in-depth-look-at-customizing-type-layout-with-resharper/) does this. One of the best investment you can do.